# Creating a pandas data frame of a specific size

Tags: python, dataframe

In R, I can do something like this:

```
myvec <- seq(from =  5, to = 10)^2
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(data = myvec, ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE))
> mydf
  X1 X2  X3
1 25 36  49
2 64 81 100
```

Notice I can specfiy the shape of the data frame by passing in an ncol parameter. I can then fill it either byrow or bycolumn (in this case by row).

If I were to replicate this in Python/Pandas, it's easy enough to create the sequence:

```
myData = [x**2 for x in range(5,11) ]
```

However, how do easily make a dataframe of the same size?
I can do something like:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame(data = myData)
```

But what would be the parameters to specify the column/row dimensions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to specify the number of columns (or rows):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

myvec = np.arange(5, 11)**2
mydf = pd.DataFrame(myvec.reshape(-1, 3))
```

yields

```
    0   1    2
0  25  36   49
1  64  81  100
```

---

When calling `reshape` you are allowed to specify the length of one axis as `-1`. 
`reshape` replaces the `-1` with whatever integer makes sense. For example, if `myvec.size` is 6, and one axis is of length 3, then the other axis has to be of length 6/3 = 2. So the `-1` is replaced by 2, and so `myvec.reshape(-1, 3)` returns an array of shape `(2, 3)` -- 2 row and 3 columns.

Comment: Hi, and then it always fills in "by row"?

Comment: Be default, `reshape` "fills by row" (in so-called "C order"). If you wish to "fill by column", use `myvec.reshape(-1, 3, order='F')`.

Comment: Perfect -- just what i needed.

Answer (score 63):

One way to make a pandas dataframe of the size you wish is to provide index and column values on the creation of the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(numRows),columns=range(numCols))
```

This creates a dataframe full of nan's where all columns are of data type object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a data frame with specific number of columns and rows all filled with None or another value repeatly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["value"]*integer_number_of_rows,"col2":["value"]*integer_number_of_rows})
```

Then you can fill up the cells with any values you want later.